# How do astronauts keep their devices dry?

Tags: iss, nasa, astronaut-lifestyle

In these videos astronauts are drinking and playing with water.
We can see water droplets floating away to the surroundings.
Do these droplets affect the machines in any way?
What do astronauts do to prevent devices getting destroyed?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5421/my-space-station-is-filling-with-water

Comment: [Like this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adpUNslsmn4)

Comment: Most electronic devices are not overly sensitive to a very few drops of water.

Answer (score 33):

Towels. Towels are used for this extensively.  Hitchhiker's Guide wasn't making this part up, at least.  Here's an 10 liter spill soaked up with towels this week.

NASA Status report: https://blogs.nasa.gov/stationreport/2019/02/01/iss-daily-summary-report-2-01-2019/

Increasing levels of toilet humor:

https://www.engadget.com/2019/02/06/iss-toilet-leak-water-crew/

https://futurism.com/the-byte/iss-toilet-russia-american

Comment: you are saying the ISS astronauts are cool and froody?

Comment: @GdD In some cases, yes: https://planetary.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/images/people/2014/20141121_exp-42-hitchhiker-poster.jpg

Comment: I love it, but where are the towels?

Comment: "a water leak while de-mating a Quick Disconnect (QD) for the *potable* water bus."  Well that could have been worse, sounds like the leak was from the supply side, not the waste one.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I agree 100%, the media is just jumping all over it because the word 'toilet' appeared in the writeup.

Answer (score 15):

For small spills, crew on board the ISS rely on evaporation to remove water that they can't mop up with towels.

The ISS [ECLSS](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/marshall/history/eclss.html) (Environment Control and Life Support System), which consists of several components spread around the station, has 2 main components for maintaining the atmosphere: Elektron on the Zvezda module, and the Air Revitalization System (ARS) on Tranquility.

Elektron is set to remove most of the water vapor to produce oxygen for the crew. However, in an emergency, both the ARS and Elektron can be used to reclaim drinking water.  (Most reclaimed drinking water that goes to the Water Processor Assembly to make it potable comes from the Urine Processor Assembly and other wastewater sources, such as sinks.)

One side effect of working in microgravity is that, if something isn't bolted down, it eventually makes its way to the life support's inlets, either to be caught by a filter, or to be processed.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is to be seen in the second video. The astronauts carefully catch the droplets with their mouth and swallow them. They should catch every single drop. The vacuum cleaner may be used too.

Astronaut Alexander Gerst said in an interview on German TV: "when we loose small parts, we find them later at the entrance mesh filter of the aircondition". (translation by me) So water droplets will be moved to the mesh filter too.

If an electronic device is cooled by forced air, there should be a filter at the air inlet too. No water drop may get into air outlet holes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sure there's spills once in a while, but I've never seen anyone miss a single drop while doing a stupid video.